# Extracting text between div tags - Simple Html Dom Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Code :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://url.com');
$ret = $html->find('div[samplediv]');
echo $ret;
```

The output I get is just Array. that means it is empty. I am sure the div is preset on the page I am scraping.

Also, another thing I am trying to achieve is, take the text from the html. when I simply convert it to plaintext, it results in lot of unwanted numbers and stuff. So what I am trying to do is, get the text that I see in the browser. (Instead of getting the whole text from the html).

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: did you mean to echo $ret instead of $html? Also, $ret->plaintext should work.

Comment: I suggest you take `DOMDocument` instead of simple html dom parser - it works much better and is much better documented and easier to extend. Also you should do `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on the top of your file and fix any warning and notice. That will in the end give you the answer to your question as well.

Comment: try using `$html->find('div[id=samplediv]');` as what you put is wrong i think

Comment: and for future reference, here is how to echo the contents: `foreach($html->find('div[id=samplediv]') as $div) {
echo $div->innertext;
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're outputting the whole document.  Try

```
echo $ret->innertext;
```

to just output the contents of the div.

PS: I just looked this up at on google and found http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Updated the answer.

Now it returns nothing other than Array. with Innertext, it returns nothing.

Comment: When an echo outputs "Array" it means the variable is not a string (but, an array).  Try var_dump() or print_r()

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same, tried print_r and it returns Array()

Comment: did you try to loop through the array to get the values? There's probably more than one element being returned.

Comment: Sounds like an empty array.  Perhaps the element you're looking for does not exist in the document.